# mysql utf8 uni charset

Tags: php, mysql, apache, utf-8

I have some german datasets im my Database. On those fields I use utf8 uni, my php and apache is also running on utf8 uni. I don't know why but mysql saves the data in this fields like that if there is some german special char

```
Mit Gummizug fÃ¼r den perfekten
```

I don't want those "Ã¼" what do I need to change to show these special chars correctly?

Comment: `$this->connect ->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query('SET character_set_client = utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query('SET character_set_results = utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query('SET character_set_connection = utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query('SET character_set_database = utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query('SET character_set_server = utf8;');
   $this->connect -> query ('SET NAMES utf8');` Worked for me in my connection class, just replace $this->connect with your $DBH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you opened the connection with mySQL in UTF8 mode? If not, I suspect this is your problem.

Assuming you're using PDO, you'd do this by appending 'charset=utf8' to your connection string.

Comment: yes, I'm using pdo ... tried this `new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));` but still the same result

Comment: also tried this `new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass);` also not working for me

Comment: @Johnny 187 - Is your PHP page encoded in UTF-8 as well, i mean the file format, not the declaration in the header? Make sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the connection object to deliver UTF-8, before making queries and inserts:

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

For other types of mysql connections have a look [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).